# Calculating n! mod m when m is not prime

Tags: c, algorithm, math, modulus

I have read a lot of good algos to calculate n! mod m but they were usually valid when m was prime . I wanted to know whether some good algo exists when m is not prime .I would be helpful if someone could write the basic function of the algo too.I have been using

```
long long factMOD(long long n,long long mod)
{
    long long res = 1; 
    while (n > 0)
    {
        for (long long i=2, m=n%mod; i<=m; i++)
        res = (res * i) % mod;
        if ((n/=mod)%2 > 0) 
        res = mod - res;
    }
    return res;
}
```

but getting wrong answer when I try to print factMOD(4,3) even. source of this algo is :
http://comeoncodeon.wordpress.com/category/algorithm/

Comment: just do all the multiplications mod m - it could not be very difficult.

Comment: [This](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/primenumbers/message/1095) - take modulo `m` whenever the result of the multiplication becomes greater than `m`.

Comment: @mvp-n is given to me of the order of 10^7.I need a better algo to do it.

Comment: Have you considered an algorithm that utilizes chained modulos? `(a*b) mod p = ((a mod p) * (b mod p)) mod p`. This could well help you with your problem, particularly when combined with an early-exit short-cut on any encounter of zero.

Comment: @WhozCraig this is actually already done as much as possible; it's just kind of implicit. The left side of the multiplication is the running product, which is already mod-m; and the right side of the multiplication should already be less than m if you apply either of the early-exit optimizations, meaning that taking it mod m is a no-op.

Comment: @hobbs using the algorithm described by H2C03 and yourself below, you're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I've come up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long long nfactmod(unsigned long long n, unsigned long long m)
{
    unsigned long long i, f;
    for (i = 1, f = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        f *= i;
        if (f > m) {
            f %= m;
        }
    }
    return f;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned long long n = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    unsigned long long m = strtoull(argv[2], NULL, 10);

    printf("%llu\n", nfactmod(n, m));

    return 0;
}
```

and this:

```
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$ ./mod 1000000 1001001779
744950559
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$
```

runs in a fraction of a second.

Comment: @Blender Quite... :-( Sad he was soooo stubborn... But you know, I must stock up of reputation because I won't have much time for SO, I'll have a busy week...

Comment: @Blender: No actually it wasn't my homework. I was going through some online good combinatorial questions and there I was stuck in one of these types.

Comment: @kavish And what's the problem with my answer that finally made you unaccept it?

Comment: @kavish And how is this different than any other suggestion made?

Comment: @H2CO3: your answer i have accepted that.  I was just being on a negative side of this approach because I thot if there are so many good algos for m prime then there would be good ones for m not prime too.

Answer (score 4):

The basic algorithm is valid for any value of `m`:

```
product := 1
for i := 2 to n
    product := (product * i) mod m
return product
```

and an easy optimization is that you can bail out early and return 0 whenever `product` becomes 0. You can also return 0 at the beginning if n > m, since that guarantees that n! is a multiple of m.

Comment: this algo won't suffice to solve my problem. I have been given n to be nearly 10^7. This will exceeede time limits by huge amount.

Comment: @kavish: Have you tried implementing it? It runs almost instantly for me in Python, which is a relatively slow language.

Comment: @kavish 10^7 is not a very big number.

Comment: @kavish Have you attempted this algorithm to check whether or not it meets your time constraints?

Comment: @Code-Guru-will it be under 1 sec for 500 such test cases?Ok i will implement it and see what happens.

Comment: @kavish See my answer. I've implemented almost the exact same algorithm (without the optimization Hobbs proposed) yet it run ***instantly*** for me for `n = 1 000 000`...